# To split only Chinese characters in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I am writing a java application; but stuck on this point.

Basically I have a string of Chinese characters with ALSO some possible Latin chars or numbers, lets say:

```
查詢促進民間參與公共建設法（210ＢＯＴ法）.
```

I want to split those Chinese chars except the Latin or numbers as "BOT" above. So, at the end I will have this kind of list:

`[ 查, 詢, 促, 進, 民, 間, 參, 與, 公, 共, 建, 設, 法, （, 210, ＢＯＴ, 法, ）, ., ]`

How can I resolve this problem (for java)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chinese characters lies within certain Unicode ranges:

- 2F00-2FDF: Kangxi
- 4E00-9FAF: CJK
- 3400-4DBF: CJK Extension

So all you basically need to do is to check if the character's codepoint lies within the known ranges. This example is a good starting point to write a stackbased parser/splitter, you only need to extend it to separate digits from latin letters, which should be obvious enough (hint: `Character#isDigit()`):

```
Set<UnicodeBlock> chineseUnicodeBlocks = new HashSet<UnicodeBlock>() {{
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_FORMS);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPHS);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_COMPATIBILITY_IDEOGRAPHS_SUPPLEMENT);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_RADICALS_SUPPLEMENT);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_SYMBOLS_AND_PUNCTUATION);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_A);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS_EXTENSION_B);
    add(UnicodeBlock.KANGXI_RADICALS);
    add(UnicodeBlock.IDEOGRAPHIC_DESCRIPTION_CHARACTERS);
}};

String mixedChinese = "查詢促進民間參與公共建設法（210ＢＯＴ法）";

for (char c : mixedChinese.toCharArray()) {
    if (chineseUnicodeBlocks.contains(UnicodeBlock.of(c))) {
        System.out.println(c + " is chinese");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " is not chinese");
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: As an extension, I believe a character class in an regexp. spanning the above unicode ranges would also work.

Comment: Not really if you also want to intercept on groups of digits/letters/hyphens/whateverlatin. A stackbased parser is a better tool for this kind of job.

Comment: @MichieldeMare Just substitute the unicode blocks in answer where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Diclaimer: I'm a complete Lucene newbie.

Using the latest version of Lucene (3.6.0 at the time of writing) I manage to get close to the result you require.

```
  Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, Collections.emptySet());

  List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("content", new StringReader(original));
  CharTermAttribute termAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

  try {
    tokenStream.reset(); // Resets this stream to the beginning. (Required)
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
      words.add(termAttribute.toString());
    }
    tokenStream.end(); // Perform end-of-stream operations, e.g. set the final offset.
  }
  finally {
    tokenStream.close(); // Release resources associated with this stream.
  }
```

The result I get is:

```
[查, 詢, 促, 進, 民, 間, 參, 與, 公, 共, 建, 設, 法, 210ｂｏｔ, 法]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach I would take.

You can use Character.codePointAt(char[] charArray, int index) to return the Unicode value for a char in your char array.

You will also need a mapping of Latin Unicode characters.

If you look in the source of Character.UnicodeBlock, the full LATIN block is the interval [0x0000, 0x0249]. So basically you check if your Unicode code point is somewhere within that interval.

I suspect there is a way to just use a Character.Subset to check if it contains your char, but I haven't looked into that.